# error : Config cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android

In the following code i am having the above error ,here i declared the variable also.

```
contentBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 300,
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        Backgroundcanvas = new Canvas(contentBitmap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recognizing `Config` as a class name. You need to either use the qualified name `Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888` or else put `import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;` at the top of the file.

Comment: here vote up requires 15 reputations ,unable to vote up.sorry for that but thanks for help.......